# I am getting all sorts of errors with this code. am I putting the try/catch in the correct place or is my code just completely messed up?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, windowbuilder

I am attempting to create a pop up window which tracks deposit/withdrawls form a bank account. I have the window created properly but I am getting a ton of errors when I created the code to do the math for the two buttons. I am pretty sure I am just inputing the code in the wrong place but I am unsure of how to fix it. This is the code I have currently. Can someone explain to me what I did wrong?

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class acmeBank {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField creditInput;
    private JTextField debitInput;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    acmeBank window = new acmeBank();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public acmeBank() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        
        double balance = 0;
        
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 470, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("DEPOSIT");
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("WITHDRAWAL");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        
        creditInput = new JTextField();
        creditInput.setColumns(10);
        
        debitInput = new JTextField();
        debitInput.setColumns(10);
        
        JButton creditButton = new JButton("CREDIT");
        creditButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        
        JButton debitButton = new JButton("DEBIT");
        debitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        
        JButton clearButton = new JButton("CLEAR");
        clearButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        
        JLabel lblNewLabel_2 = new JLabel("BALANCE    $");
        lblNewLabel_2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        
        JLabel totalBalance = new JLabel("");
        GroupLayout groupLayout = new GroupLayout(frame.getContentPane());
        groupLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(47)
                            .addComponent(lblNewLabel_2)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(totalBalance, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(Alignment.LEADING, groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(18)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(lblNewLabel, Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(lblNewLabel_1, Alignment.TRAILING))
                            .addGap(0)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                .addComponent(debitInput, Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(creditInput, Alignment.TRAILING, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 124, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(debitButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 76, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(creditButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 80, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18)
                    .addComponent(clearButton, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 78, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(39, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        groupLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(23)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblNewLabel)
                                .addComponent(creditInput, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(creditButton))
                            .addGap(11)
                            .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(lblNewLabel_1)
                                .addComponent(debitInput, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(debitButton)))
                        .addGroup(groupLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(40)
                            .addComponent(clearButton)))
                    .addGap(33)
                    .addGroup(groupLayout.createParallelGroup(Alignment.TRAILING)
                        .addComponent(lblNewLabel_2)
                        .addComponent(totalBalance, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addContainerGap(122, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);
    
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if (e.getSource() == creditButton) {

                try {
                    
                    double amount = Double.parseDouble(creditInput.getText());
                    balance += amount;
                    totalBalance.setText("$" + balance);
                    

                } catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
                    
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Please enter only numbers");
                }
            } else if (e.getSource() == debitButton) {
                try {
                    
                    double amount = Double.parseDouble(debitInput.getText());

                    balance -= amount;
                    totalBalance.setText("$" + balance);
                   

                } catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
                    
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f, "Please enter only numbers");
                }
            } else if (e.getSource() == clearButton) {
    
                debitInput.setText("");
                creditInput.setText("");
            }
        }

      
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new ACMEBank();
        }
    }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: We (& by 'we' I mean the person writing the code, i.e. 'you') need to approach compilation errors starting with the first in the code. That will often fix later problems. A tip for the first is that it seems to put a method inside another method or constructor. Take it outside the scope of that code block it's in.

Comment: Everything after `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(groupLayout);` and the last two `}` needs to moved, as it's within the `initialize` method.  Take the code mentioned and move it to just above the last `}`

Comment: @MadProgrammer i tried that already and it is still giving me errors. can I not use

```java
e.getSource() == creditButton)
```

on line 145. all of of variables are not initializing

Comment: @FingerLessB That's because the `creditButton` is a local variable, if you want to access it outside of the method it's declared in, then you're going to need to make it a instance variable.  Better yet, make use of the `ActionEvent#getActionCommand`.  You also seem to have two `main` methods

Comment: @FingerLessB Your codes a mess, you seem to be copy/pasting code together.  First, stop using form editors, they are not helping your here, in fact, they've made a complete mess for your code.  Start by having a look at [How to Write an Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) and [How to Use Buttons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [Declaring Member Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer everything except for the  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) section was done through the windowbuilder so I didn't write the code, eclipse did. Everything else was done by "copy paste" as I am unsure how to do it so I looked up how action listner is used and tried to piece the information together myself. I will look at the though thank you. 

I am unsure what ActionEvent#getActionCommand is. and yes the second main method was a mistake and I removed it.

Comment: [`ActionEvent#getActionCommand`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand()) so you don't need the source of the event and an action can be trigged by a number of different mechanisms, ie a menu, a button, a key stroke

Answer (score 0):

Beware of form editors, even an experience developer can completely screw up an otherwise simple interface/code without much effort. They don't teach you about things like decoupling and single responsibility and soon, you can have a "god" class which is completely out of control.

Generally speaking, code generated by form editors is also difficult to update, maintain and fix, best to do without.

The primary "issue" is the fact that you're trying to declare methods within methods, Java doesn't allow you do this.

The "associated" issues come down to the fact that variables your are trying to access are declared locally (with the `initialize` method), if you want to access them, you should declare them as instance variables instead.

Having said that, if you take advantage of `ActionEvent#getActionCommand` you won't need to (personally, I make use of [Anonymous Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), but I think that's a little beyond you right now and it's also a danger of coming to a QA site like this, we won't take into account your current "learning" level and just throw all sorts of "cool" stuff at you, which won't actually help you become a better developer, just saying)

The following is basically hand written version of your code...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ACMEBank {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ACMEBank();
    }

    public ACMEBank() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private JTextField depositField;
        private JTextField withdrawField;

        private JLabel balanceLabel;

        private double balance;

        public TestPane() {
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(16, 16, 16, 16));
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            depositField = new JTextField(10);
            withdrawField = new JTextField(10);
            balanceLabel = new JLabel("0.00");

            JButton creditBtn = new JButton("Credit");
            JButton debitBtn = new JButton("Debit");
            JButton clearBtn = new JButton("Clear");

            JPanel inputPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);

            inputPane.add(new JLabel("Deposit"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            inputPane.add(new JLabel("Widthdraw"), gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            inputPane.add(depositField, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            inputPane.add(withdrawField, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            inputPane.add(creditBtn, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            inputPane.add(debitBtn, gbc);

            JPanel balancePane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;

            balancePane.add(new JLabel("Balance $"), gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            balancePane.add(balanceLabel, gbc);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            add(inputPane, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            add(balancePane, gbc);

            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(clearBtn, gbc);

            // I'd prefer to use anoymouse class here to isoldate the functionality
            // and make it easier to deal with, but that's not how the originla code
            // works
            debitBtn.addActionListener(this);
            creditBtn.addActionListener(this);
            clearBtn.addActionListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if ("credit".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())) {
                try {
                    double amount = Double.parseDouble(depositField.getText());
                    balance += amount;
                    balanceLabel.setText("$" + balance);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter only numbers");
                }
            } else if ("debit".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())) {
                try {
                    double amount = Double.parseDouble(withdrawField.getText());
                    balance -= amount;
                    balanceLabel.setText("$" + balance);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ee) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please enter only numbers");
                }
            } else if ("clear".equalsIgnoreCase(e.getActionCommand())) {
                withdrawField.setText("");
                depositField.setText("");
            }
        }

    }
}
```